# Can I use maven-style project on git as dependency?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

Can I use maven-style project on git as dependency ? I'm trying to add following project: https://github.com/jconwell/coreNlp

In my `build.scala` it's specified as

```
lazy val root = Project(
) dependsOn(coreNlpExtProject)
lazy val coreNlpExtProject = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/jconwell/coreNlp.git"))
```

Oddly on `sbt update` I get error

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: default#corenlp_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

What is it referring to ? I don't see anything with version `0.1-SNAPSHOT` in `pom.xml`